# 3+ dimensional truth table in APL

Tags: arrays, complexity-theory, apl

I would like to enumerate all the combinations (tuples of values) of 3 or more finite-valued variables which satisfy a given condition. In math notation:

[image]

For example (inspired by [Project Euler problem 9](http://projecteuler.net/problem=9)):

[image]

The truth tables for two variables at a time are easy enough:

```
    a ∘.≤ b
1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1
0 0 1 1
    b ∘.≤ c
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1
```

After much head-scratching, I managed to combine them, by computing the ∧ of every 4-valued row of the former with each 4-valued column of the latter, and disclosing (⊃) on the correct axis, between 1 and 2:

```
    ⎕← tt ← ⊃[1.5] (⊂[2] a ∘.≤ b) ∘.∧ (⊂[1] b ∘.≤ c)
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1

0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1

0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1
```

Then I could use its ravel to filter all possible tuples of values:

```
    ⊃ (,tt) / , a ∘., b ∘., c
1 1 1                       
1 1 2                       
1 1 3                       
1 1 4                       
1 1 5                       
1 2 2                       
1 2 3                       
...
3 3 5                       
3 4 4                       
3 4 5
```

Is this the best approach to this particular class of problems in APL?

Is there an easier or faster formula for this example, or for the general case?

---

More generally, comparing my (naïve?) array approach above to traditional scalar languages, I can see that I'm translating each loop into an additional dimension: 3 nested loops become a 3-rank truth table:

```
for c in 1..NC:
    for b in 1..min(c, NB):
        for a in 1..min(b, NA):
            collect (a,b,c)
```

But in a scalar language one can effect optimizations along the way, for example breaking loops as soon as possible, or choosing the loop boundaries dynamically. In this case I don't even need to test for a ≤ b ≤ c, because it's implicit in the loop boundaries.

In this example both approaches have O(N³) complexity, so their runtime will only differ by a factor. But I'm wondering: how could I write the array solution in a more optimized way, if I needed to do so?

Are there any good books or online resources that address algorithmic issues or best practices in APL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach.  I'm not sure if it would run faster.
Following your algorithm for scalar languages, the possible values of `c` are

```
⎕IO←0
c←1+⍳NC
```

In the inner loops the values for `b` and `a` are

```
b←1+⍳¨NB⌊c
a←1+⍳¨¨NA⌊b
```

If we combine those

```
r←(⊂¨¨¨a,¨¨¨b),¨¨¨c
```

we get a nested array of (a,b,c) triplets which can be flattened and rearranged in a matrix

```
r←∊r
(((⍴r)÷3),3)⍴r
```

---

ADD:

Morten Kromberg sent me the following solution.  On Dyalog APL it's ~ 30 times more efficient than the one above:

```
⎕IO←1
AddDim←{0≡⍵:⍪⍳⍺ ⋄ n←0⌈⍺-x←¯1+⊢/⍵ ⋄ (n⌿⍵),∊x+⍳¨n} 
TTable←{⊃AddDim/⌽0,⍵}
TTable 3 4 5
```

Comment: That's really cool! Yes, I can see how in my example it would be faster to just compute the entire array, but this is the kind of approach I was unable to find. I must admit I've still not grokked `¨`. I use it, but in a kind of fearful way :-) I'd be more comfortable with the rank operator `⍤`, lovely thing specified in ISO 13751 but overlooked by most implementations :-(

Comment: The rank operator looks like a lovely thing, indeed.  I should spend some time getting to grips with it.  As for ISO, I have no interest in following a paywalled "standard".

Comment: As a matter of principle, I understand your misgivings on the paywall thing. But that's just how things are in this age. That standard was compiled by some well renowned experts in the APL world with great care and effort and it's become one of my references for studying the language (besides, there's a free copy [here](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~ljdickey/apl-rep/docs/is13751.pdf)‎)